# Getting Id by custom attribute value

Tags: attributes

I have looked and tried for days, so I am going to try asking here. 
I need to scan a barcode and through that, get a product from the magento store. 
I have been trying to use these to get some results but no luck.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('module/model_name')->getCollection()
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)
```

I can get Id through the SKU, but that's about it. Can anyone help me with this issue? I would appreciate your help very much.

If this is not possible, would it be possible to make a custom attribute like the sku? (Super attribute or what they are called). So I would be able to get it like the sku?

**This is what I ended up doing:**

> $scannerData = $_REQUEST["q"];  //The scanned data
>
> $catId = 2; //Categori id - 2 is root
>
> $categories = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
>
> $categories->load($catId);
>
> $collection = $categories->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('ean')
>   ->addAttributeToFilter('ean', $scannerData);
>
> foreach ($collection as $product){
>
> $product_id = $product->getId();
>   $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
>   }

//Do whatever with the product here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good idea to have a static attribute (added to `catalog_product_entity`) so you can put an index on it.

Beside this it should be easily possible to use:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('barcode_attribute_name', $scannedBarcode)
```

Comment: If I am able to make the attribute static, it would solve all my problems! I did not know that. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there a guide how to make EAN/barcode statis? I can surely see the benefits

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3972/attribute-backend-type-static